# How to access it's static constant from instance of an object?

Tags: class, flutter, dart

I have an object that has `static constant` which I need to reach from its instance.

```
class ChatsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  var arguments;
  static const name = ADatas.chatRoute;

  ChatsScreen(this.arguments);

  createState() => ChatsScreenState();
}
```

In above class' State object, I want to call `static const name`. Above class' State object's code:

```
class ChatsScreenState extends State<ChatsScreen> with RouteHelper{
  String userName = "";

  var textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    getRouteName(widget); //=> as I understand and see on the VSCode, its the ChatsScreen object. 
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

I'm trying to implement an interface so I don't know the actually class name while writing the interface. And I thought that I can reach its static constant if I know its actual class. And I wrote something like this but it seems not to be possible. I guess I have a misunderstanding.

```
class RouteHelper{
  String getRouteName(dynamic instance){
    if(instance is StatefulWidget){
      return instance.runtimeType.name; // => !!!
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I'm not trying to get the route name in actual. It's just a concept that i used in this question, so please don't refer better way to get the route name in flutter.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like that, people have talked about this in [this issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34131).

However you can kinda do it using class members and typing system.

```
abstract class Routed {
  String getClassRoute();
}

class ChatsScreen extends StatefulWidget implements Routed {
  var arguments;
  static const name = "myexampleroutename";

  ChatsScreen(this.arguments);

  createState() => ChatsScreenState();

  @override
  String getClassRoute() {
    return ChatsScreen.name;
  }
}

class RouteHelper {
  String getRouteName(Routed instance) {
    return instance.getClassRoute();
  }
}
```

I said you can't, but with [dart:mirrors](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-mirrors/dart-mirrors-library.html) it is possible, however it is [banned](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/1150) on Flutter packages. There is [reflectable](https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable) package that tries to fix that using code generation, but I am not aware of it's status/reliability.

Comment: I actually didn't want to write [ClassName].name by overriding for every class. Thus I asked the question. You clarified the limitations, thanks though.